# SQL Update with AVG of Joined Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to update the supplier lead time in a table by calculating the difference between date of order and stock receipt date....

```
UPDATE cr_accs 
SET    cr_accs.leadtime = Avg(Datediff(day, purchord_hdr.orderdate, 
                                     stock_trans.transdate)) 
FROM   stock_items 
       INNER JOIN stock_trans 
               ON stock_trans.stockcode = stock_items.stockcode 
       INNER JOIN purchord_hdr 
               ON purchord_hdr.seqno = stock_trans.ref1 
WHERE   cr_accs.accno = purchord_hdr.accno 
       AND stock_trans.location = 1 
       AND stock_trans.ref2 = 'RECEIPT'
       AND purchord_hdr.orderdate >= Dateadd(day, Datediff(day, 0, Getdate()),-730) 
       AND stock_items.isactive = 'Y' 
       AND stock_items.bincode NOT IN ( 'OIO', 'CON' )
```

However I'm getting an error

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement

I've seen other solutions where you would change the query to:

```
UPDATE cr_accs 
SET    cr_accs.leadtime = h.calc_lead_time
FROM   (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(day, purchord_hdr.orderdate, stock_trans.transdate)) AS calc_lead_time  
        FROM stock_items 
       INNER JOIN stock_trans 
               ON stock_trans.stockcode = stock_items.stockcode 
       INNER JOIN purchord_hdr 
               ON purchord_hdr.seqno = stock_trans.ref1  
       INNER JOIN cr_accs 
               ON cr_accs.accno = purchord_hdr.accno 
WHERE   cr_accs.accno = purchord_hdr.accno  
       AND stock_trans.location = 1 
       AND stock_trans.ref2 = 'RECEIPT' 
       AND purchord_hdr.orderdate >= Dateadd(day, Datediff(day, 0, Getdate()),-730) 
       AND stock_items.isactive = 'Y' 
       AND stock_items.bincode NOT IN ( 'OIO', 'CON' ) ) h
```

However this is not the solution for me as it doesn't define that the lead time is unique to each supplier...
It may be helpful to point out that each supplier is identified by cr_accs.accno

Any ideas please?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and in standard SQL, there is no `FROM` clause for the UPDATE command). [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do what you want using a correlated subquery, which might be what you were trying to do:

```
UPDATE cr_accs 
    SET cr_accs.leadtime =
         (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(day, p.orderdate, st.transdate)) AS calc_lead_time  
          FROM stock_items si JOIN
               stock_trans st
               ON st.stockcode = si.stockcode JOIN
               purchord_hdr p
               ON p.seqno = st.ref1  
          WHERE cr_accs.accno = p.accno  AND
                st.location = 1 AND
                st.ref2 = 'RECEIPT' AND
                p.orderdate >= Dateadd(day, Datediff(day, 0, Getdate()), -730) AND
                si.isactive = 'Y' AND
                si.bincode NOT IN ( 'OIO', 'CON' )
         );
```

I introduced table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

SQL Server also gives you the ability to express this using `APPLY`:

```
UPDATE a 
    SET a.leadtime = p.calc_lead_time
    FROM cr_accs a CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(day, p.orderdate, st.transdate)) AS calc_lead_time  
          FROM stock_items si JOIN
               stock_trans st
               ON st.stockcode = si.stockcode JOIN
               purchord_hdr p
               ON p.seqno = st.ref1  
          WHERE a.accno = p.accno  AND
                st.location = 1 AND
                st.ref2 = 'RECEIPT' AND
                p.orderdate >= Dateadd(day, Datediff(day, 0, Getdate()), -730) AND
                si.isactive = 'Y' AND
                si.bincode NOT IN ( 'OIO', 'CON' )
         ) p;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff - this does work thank you :-) Your answer updates every single supplier leadtime in the table, regardless of whether the were any purchases within two years (>= 730 days) - where there is no purchases the leadtime is null...(correctly). @forpas solution works as well - however only updates the suppliers where there has been purchases (902 rows affected vs 235 between the two queries). So both are correct depending what you want the result to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this join of the table to the query:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.leadtime = h.calc_lead_time
FROM cr_accs c 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT purchord_hdr.accno,
    AVG(DATEDIFF(day, purchord_hdr.orderdate, stock_trans.transdate)) AS calc_lead_time  
  FROM stock_items 
  INNER JOIN stock_trans ON stock_trans.stockcode = stock_items.stockcode 
  INNER JOIN purchord_hdr ON purchord_hdr.seqno = stock_trans.ref1  
  WHERE      stock_trans.location = 1 
         AND stock_trans.ref2 = 'RECEIPT' 
         AND purchord_hdr.orderdate >= Dateadd(day, Datediff(day, 0, Getdate()),-730) 
         AND stock_items.isactive = 'Y' 
         AND stock_items.bincode NOT IN ('OIO', 'CON') 
  GROUP BY purchord_hdr.accno
) h ON h.accno = c.accno
```

I assume (by your code and the error message) that you are using SQL Server.